# RxSwift Test fails now .delay has been introduced

Tags: swift, unit-testing, delay, rx-swift

I have a the following code -

```swift
        viewIsReady
            .flatMapLatest { [unowned self] _ in self.dependencies.authSvc.checkSession().asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: false) }
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .delay(.seconds(2), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance) <-- without this test passes
            .bind(to: checkSessionComplete)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

We have a splash view that is presented and want to show this for a minimum time each time. As this view is dismissed by emiting to `checkSessionComplete` I have added a delay, to allow the async operation to complete and prevent the sequence moving along.

However the test for this is now failing, but the behaviour is correct.

How Should I test an operation that includes the `delay` operator?

```
   func test_on_check_session_response_emits() {
        let deps = TestDependencies()
        deps.authSvcSpy.stubbedCheckSessionResult = .just(true)

        DependencyInjector.dependencies = deps

        scheduler.scheduleAt(0) {
            self.sut.viewIsReady.onNext(())
        }

        let observer = scheduler.createObserver(AuthState.self)

        sut.checkSessionComplete
        .asObservable()
        .bind(to: observer)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        scheduler.start()

        XCTAssertEqual(observer.events.count, 1)
    }
```

**EDIT**

Based on the answer below I have updated my `Presenter` -

```swift
final class StartPresenter {

    // Input
    let viewIsReady = PublishSubject<Void>()

    // Output
    let checkSessionComplete = PublishSubject<Void>()

    var scheduler: SchedulerType = MainScheduler.instance

    weak private var view: StartViewInterface?

    private lazy var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init(view: StartViewInterface?) {
        self.view = view

        viewIsReady
            .flatMapLatest { [unowned self] _ in self.dependencies.authSvc.checkSession().asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: false) }
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .mapToVoid()
            .delay(.seconds(2), scheduler: scheduler)
            .bind(to: checkSessionComplete)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

and my test case

```
    func test_on_check_session_response_emits() {
         let deps = TestDependencies()
         deps.authSvcSpy.stubbedCheckSessionResult = .just(true)
         DependencyInjector.dependencies = deps

        sut.scheduler = testScheduler

        testScheduler.scheduleAt(0) {
            self.sut.viewIsReady.onNext(())
        }

        let observer = testScheduler.createObserver(Void.self)

        sut.checkSessionComplete
        .asObservable()
        .delay(.seconds(2), scheduler: testScheduler)
        .bind(to: observer)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        testScheduler.start()

        XCTAssertEqual(observer.events.count, 1)
    }

}
```

And the test is still failing if the `.delay` is in the chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you are using `MainScheduler.instance` which won't work during tests. You need to inject the test scheduler and use that one eg: `.delay(.seconds(2), scheduler: scheduler)`.

Comment: Thank you, I have added an update as the test is still failing, is this the correct way to implement this change?

Comment: It is still failing because your code is wrong. `.delay(.seconds(2), scheduler: scheduler)` inside `StartPresenter` is computed at init time using `MainScheduler`. During tests, you are changing it by doing `sut.scheduler = testScheduler` but the rx chain is not recomputed and so it is still using `MainScheduler`.